# Counting number of words and characters from several lines of user input

Tags: java

**Description:** *"Write a program to read several lines of text (each line ending with a '.') from Scanner. It should count the number of words and the number of non-space characters. The program should stop accepting input when it reads the word (DONE) in a separate line of input."*

I'm having trouble with this program. Whenever I input the sample text and type in DONE, the number of words and characters match that of only the word 'DONE'. If someone could provide a working fix, that would be very helpful towards my understanding of the problems at hand.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter text (type DONE to quit): ");
    String text = "";
    while (!"DONE".equals(text)) {
        text = input.next();
    }
    String[] numOfWords = text.split(" ");
    String[] numOfChars = text.split("");
    System.out.print("Number of words: " + numOfWords.length);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Number of non-space characters: " + numOfChars.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting `text` in every iteration of the while loop, you don't keep the input from previous iterations.

Comment: What happens is that at last you enter DONE so it counted DONE only

Comment: Okay, so I made a few changes based on your comments.
The while loop now looks like this:
while (!text.contains("DONE")) {
   text += input.next();
  }
However now when I run it DONE will not terminate the input.

Comment: @Lev1athan909 Well, yes. For your last version of the loop to end, `text` must contain "DONE", hence it's counted in everything else you do later on. You can just call `substring()` with the appropriate parameters to overwrite `text` with the contents of `text` minus the last four characters, though.

Answer (score 2):

As the answer above is incorrect (doesnt compile or work) you could try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter text (type DONE to quit): ");
    String text = "";
    String output = "";
    while (!"DONE".equals(text)) {
        text = input.next();
        output += text.replace("DONE", "") + " ";
    }
    String[] numOfWords = output.split(" ");
    String[] numOfChars = output.split("");
    System.out.print("Number of words: " + numOfWords.length);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Number of non-space characters: " + numOfChars.length);
}
```

Effectively creating another storage for the input string and once the DONE keyword is supplied exit the loop after removing the word "DONE".

Answer (score 1):

In your code what happens is that at last you give the input is DONE so it counts only done use the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter text (type DONE to quit): ");
    String text = "";
    while (true) {
        if(!text.equals("DONE")){
                 break;
         }
        text += " " + input.nextLine();
         
    }
    String[] numOfWords = text.split(" ");
    String[] numOfChars = text.split("");
    System.out.print("Number of words: " + numOfWords.length);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Number of non-space characters: " + 
     numOfChars.length);
}
```

}

Comment: I hope it helped

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis in the `if`. Also, both this code and the original code don't account for the possible lack of spaces if the input is entered one word at a time, in which case they give an output stating that there is only one word.

Comment: Have you tested it? You'll be surprised if you do. You shouldn't post answers if you aren't sure the code does what it should do.

Comment: Yes it tells the correct number of words but not characters

Comment: It tells neither number correctly in my tests. If I enter the following five inputs it tells me there is one word, not four as it should: text, with, four, words, DONE (ignore the commas, they are just a separator in this comment, for the test I entered them in different lines).

Comment: What about chars

Answer (score 1):

Both of the other answers fail to fix the error in counting the number of characters. The following code correctly accounts for lack of spaces, gets rid of the input termination text, and correctly counts the non-space characters:

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter text (type DONE to quit): ");
        String text = "";
        String output = "";
        while (!"DONE".equals(text)) {
            text = input.next();
            output += text.replace("DONE", "") + " ";
        }
        String[] numOfWords = output.split(" ");
        int numOfChars = output.replace(" ", "").length();
        System.out.print("Number of words: " + numOfWords.length);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Number of non-space characters: " + numOfChars);
    }
}
```

**Input**: *text with four words DONE*

**Output**

Please enter text (type DONE to quit):

Number of words: 4

Number of non-space characters: 17